# Split values in Millions,Thousands,Units in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

How to get a value split in Billions,millions,thousands,Units and decimals in spark sql

At the moment I tried the below options

**Thousands** - ABS(Amount)%1000000 Output : 562191.7974663
**Units** - ABS(Amount)%1000   Output : 191.7974663
**Decimals** - ABS(Amount)%1 Output : 0.7974663 or -0.56724

However, I am looking for an output as per below table.

```
Amount                   Amt_Billions    Amt_Millions   Amt_Thousands   Amt_Units  Amt_Decimals
3946562191.7974663       3000000000      946000000      562000          191        7974663
-743245613.56724                         743000000      245000          613        56724
```

Please can anyone help me with this calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the orders of magnitude like so.

```
floor(abs(Amount)%1000000000000/1000000000)*1000000000 Billions,
floor(abs(Amount)%1000000000/1000000)*1000000 Millions,
floor(abs(Amount)%1000000/1000)*1000 Thousands,
floor(abs(Amount)%1000) Units
```

Converting the decimal portion I think you will have to resort to a string expression, ie cast to string, find the index of the "." then take the right(string,len(string)-index), finally cast to int, unless it's just for display purposes of course.

Comment: Thank you.. This works perfect. I wouldnt want to cast my values to strings only because my table is very huge and that simply takes more time with the other calculations I have.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . .

```
floor(amount / 1000000000) * 1000000000 as billions,
floor((amount % 1000000000) / 1000000) * 1000000 as millions,
floor((amount % 1000000) / 1000) * 1000) as thousands,
floor(amount % 1000) as units
```

The decimals are the only tricky ones.  The numbers don't make sense, because 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 would all resolve to `1`.  I would suggest doing this in some units, such as millions:

```
floor((amount % 1) * 1000000) as units
```